# Which software is good for virtual machine over Windows for Linux and Mac OSX?

Tags: linux, mac, virtual-machine

What software is good for virtual machine over Windows for Linux and Mac OS? I want to host Linux (Web development related to Rails and PHP) and Mac (iPhone and iPad) both over Windows XP.

My specs are:

```
Intel Processor 3.4Ghz dual core
D955xbk Motherboard
4 GB Ram
```

This is all I can provide relative to my requirement

Comment: Are you asking for a VM to host Windows under Linux or MacOS? Or are you trying to run Linux or MacOS as a guest under a VM in Windows?

Comment: Want to run Linux or MacOS as a guest under a VM in Windows

Answer (score 1):

The main alternatives are:

- VMWare
- Virtual Box
- Virtual PC

All of them are free (or have a free version) for personal use, and usually also for some commercial uses.

Regarding performance, from my experience it's by the order I specified - but it's not based on a comprehensive evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

[VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org) is available for running on Windows, Linux and MacOS X.  It fully supports running Windows, Linux and MacOS X as guest operating systems, so which ever combination you want to use should work OK.

Comment: Mac OS X isn't officially supported as guest OS on non-Mac host machines (machines that are not branded with an apple logo, as required by the OS X EULA)

Comment: for more info see http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch14.html

Comment: @lajuette true, but if you have virtualisation support in hardware then OS X works on VirtualBox.

Comment: @lajuette and I didn't say that the company supported it - the software supports it.  It may not be "official", but it does.

Comment: @lajuette Mac OS X Server is licensed to be used as a client on Apple Hardware. If you run Windows using Boot Camp, you should be in the clear. At least license terms of three years ago stated: *You may also install and use other copies of Mac OS X Server Software on the same Apple-labeled computer, provided that you acquire an individual and valid license from Apple for each of these other copies of Mac OS X Server Software*

Comment: I don't think he deserved a downvote for stating what it supports

Comment: Can you guide me the way to do it If possible for Mac

Answer (score 0):

[VMWare](http://www.vmware.com/) is by far the best virtual machine solution, but only [VMPlayer](http://downloads.vmware.com/d/info/desktop_downloads/vmware_player/3_0) is free, not [VMWorkstation](http://downloads.vmware.com/d/info/desktop_downloads/vmware_workstation/7_0) (which is far superior).  [Virtual Box](http://www.virtualbox.org/) and [Virtual PC](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=04d26402-3199-48a3-afa2-2dc0b40a73b6&displaylang=en) are good too and are free, but both are a far cry from VMWare.

Comment: VMWare Player is free and the later versions allow you to create your own virtual machines.

Comment: @Matt H I have updated my answer to reflect that fact.

Answer (score 0):

As i understood your question you want to run Linux & Mac OS X in a virtual machine on a Windows host.

As the other answers stated there are multiple options.

- VirtualBox - open source, free (for private use?)
- VMWare - my choice since it's the most flexible and stable option (...personal opinion)
- Virtual PC - I used it once and i wasn't really happy with it.

About running OS X:
It's not allowed to run OS X on non-Mac host machines (machines that are not branded with an apple logo, as required by the OS X EULA)
That includes virtual machines. So running OS X on a PC might be possible but not legal.

Comment: Is any free version of VMWare available for free whihc you consider a best option over Virtual Box